# Poly/ML interpreter/compiler directly in emacs

Tags: emacs, interpreter, sml, polyml

I have installed sml-mode in emacs 24. I want to compile the code directly in emacs with Poly/ML how do I do that? I have installed Poly/ML and then typed sml-poly-ml in order to start the interpreter but i says no match. I tested both on windows and ubuntu. What to do?

UPDATED: I´m wounder if some of this:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.emacs/jlOX_aP6j40/afuuUlVemWUJ   or   http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/98-linear/lib/emacs/sml-poly-ml.el  will work? I´m be trying to reading but don´´t fully understand. I think i should put (autoload 'sml-poly-ml "sml-poly-ml" "Set up and run Poly/ML." t) in .emacs.d? What is emacs lisp files? I seems to need sml-poly-ml.el and don´t know if that is included in sml-mode as standard? Then I´m stuck...

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked with Poly/ML, however I have done some programming in SML/NJ using `sml-mode` my answer is based on this limited experience.

You can use `C-c C-s` or do `M-x run-sml RET` to start `sml` interpreter, `sml-compile` is bound to `C-c C-c`.

BTW a much better way of finding out mode specific keybindings is to do `C-h m` or `M-x describe-mode RET`.

Comment: I cannot write M-x run-sml RET. Whar do RET stands for? I did M-x run-sml and got a prompt:SML:command, where I put the location to my .sml file. But it says spawning schild process invalid argument.In the file I only have the basic funktion: fun f x = x * x; So how do you use SML/NJ? Updated my first post.

Comment: Oh sorry for being unclear, `RET` mean press `enter`. So after `M-x run-sml RET` you will be prompted for the `command` this is the name or path to the ML executable, in my case it will be `sml`, in your case it will be the name or path to the `poly/ml` executable.

Comment: sml doesn´t work for me. I have poly/ml installed on windows. But the only files installed is PolyMl.exe and PolyLib.dll. How should the executable file extension be? It is enough to write the path to the executable for poly/ml I mean I should´nt edit some file inside emacs?

Comment: You can set `sml-program-name` to the path of your executable, something like `(setq sml-program-name "/path/to/polyml.exe")`.